# Trying simple GET query for Firebase Real Time Database, get error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I've gotten the Firebase real time database up and connected with my next.js application. I'm now trying to do a GET on the database but running into a strange error. I know I have connected to the right database because when I log the name of the database, the database name is correct. If any other details are needed please let me know.

```
get(child(database, `patent_id/${input}`)).then((snapshot) => {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
  } else {
    console.log("No data available");
  }
}).catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

My error message:

> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pieceNum_')

Here is also a screenshot of the error:
[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meKKo.png)

Comment: what's the value of `database`?

Comment: const database = getDatabase(app);

Comment: according to the [database package reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/database.md#child), `child()` expects a `DatabaseReference` as the first parameter, so in this case database should be: `const database = ref(getDatabase())`. Don't forget to `import {ref} from "firebase/database"`. There is an actual example in the realtime database [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get).